# Mkdir not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Mkdir is not working. In the logs I get the following messages:

> 12-23 15:51:18.290 21326-21326/com.example.joche.mywarranty E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
>
> 12-23 15:51:21.050 21326-21326/com.example.joche.mywarranty W/System.err: mkdir failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) : /testom.example.joche.mywarranty E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2

I tried troubleshooting and have the following permissions in my AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is my code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 100);
    }
File newFile = new File("/test");
if (!newFile.exists() || !newFile.isDirectory())
{
    newFile.mkdir();
}
```

Also asked permissions on runtime:

How can I solve this? Do I maybe don't have the correct permissions?

Comment: `newFile.mkdir();`. Check the return value! `if ( ! newFile.mkdir()){ Toast ( ... could not create directory...); return; }`.

Comment: Can you post code in such a way that we do not have to scroll half an hour?

Comment: Please post the value of `newFile.getAbsolutePath()`.`

Comment: `Can you post code in such a way that we do not have to scroll half an hour?`

Comment: You did not add the code to check the return value of mkdirs()!

Comment: Terrible! `if (!newFile.exists() || !newFile.isDirectory())` That should be `if (!newFile.exists() )`

Answer (score 1):

For Android 6+ you need to add code to ask the user to confirm the requested permissions.

Google for runtime opermissions.

```
File newFile = new File("/test");
```

That will never succeede. Try in external storage:

```
File newFile = newFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test");
```

Comment: `/stprage/emulated//test`  ??? Indeed. That path is not on your phone. Nor on mines. Please dont tell that it is the result of newFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test").

Comment: And now... is de directory created?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0` is on your phone. Like on mines. And you try to create a directory `/storage/emulated/0/test`.

Comment: `Please learn to read:` ??? What an attitude! You wrote `/stprage/emulated//test` and then deleted it.